# RxJS equivalent of Async.js mapLimit

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, rxjs, async.js

Async.js [mapLimit](https://github.com/caolan/async#documentation) and its family of `<name>Limit` functions basically work like a semaphore: they allow a limited number of tasks to run concurrently while the extra incoming tasks are added to a queue. The queue becomes a (cold? connected?) producer. The task runner drains an item from the queue as soon as a spot becomes available (one of its tasks finishes).

This way a limited number of concurrent tasks are always active.

How can I achieve a similar functionality in RxJS?

Comment: Sure you can use smth like [`flatMapWithMaxConcurrent`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/flatmapwithmaxconcurrent.md) also if you need know about other alternatives for async you can read this page http://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/mappingr_rxjs_from_different_libraries/async/index.html

Comment: @xgrommx I've seen your useful docs, but there's no mention of any equivalent to `<name>Limit` functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A combination of `defer` and `flatMapWithMaxConcurrent` is the RxJs way to do it:

```
// returns a promise
function runSomeJob(input) { ... }

function runSomeJobObservable(input) {
    return Rx.Observable.defer(function () {
        return runSomeJob(input);
    });
}

var inputStream = // some Rx.Observable

// only allow 5 jobs to run concurrently
var outputStream = inputStream
    .flatMapWithMaxConcurrent(5, runSomeJobObservable);

ouputStream.subscribe(...);
```